# Django forms: Have default value for "choices" where "choice" source is from database

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say I have this Form in my forms.py:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES= ((1,'Cat1'), 
                (2,'Cat2'), 
                (3,'Cat3'), 
                (4,'Cat4'), 
               ) 

class AddMessageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    groupname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput) 
    categories = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, required=True) 
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Now, the CATEGORY_CHOICES is "hard-coded". This works but I need the CATEGORY_CHOICES to be added at the views.py - I need to do some dbqueries to get the "categories" under each group.

How would I do this?

PS: I managed to do the same for the HiddenInput (groupname) in my views.py by doing something like this:

```
form = AddMessageForm(
            initial={'groupname': groupname},
        )
```

I hope I made my question clear. Any clarifications, etc. please add a comment.

Regards. W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the choices at form construction

```
class AddMessageForm(forms.Form):
....
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['categories'].choices = \ 
            [(x.id, x.title) for x in MyObject.objects.all()]
        super(AddMessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you really want to do it in views.py, the method is the same.

```
myform.fields['categories'].choices = \
    [(x.id, x.title) for x in Category.objects.all()]
```

Comment: What is "MyNewChoices" in views.py method? Will it just be the result of a dbquery?

Comment: `choices` accepts a list of tuples, anything in the following format: `[('value', 'display_value'), ('value', 'display_value')]` (just like your example above) it will not accept a queryset. Updated post with example